# Comments not permitted after continuation character?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

The following works fine:

```
if (  $a -eq 2 `
  -or $a -eq 3 )
  { write-host "Hi" }
```

but not the following:

```
if (  $a -eq 2 ` #...
  -or $a -eq 3 )
  { write-host "Hi" }
```

Why?

Neither does this:

```
if (  $a -eq 2 
  -or $a -eq 3 )
  { write-host "Hi" }
```

Comment: The line continuation character is just the escape character applied to the end of the line I think so it makes sense that it needs to be the end of the line (and can't be in a comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you are telling powershell to escape the next character when you use the backtick character. It can be used as a line continuation character if used as the last character of a line because it is then escaping the carriage return and turning it from a logical End-Of-Line marker and converting it into a literal carriage return that does nothing more but move to the text to the beginning of the next line. It will fail to act as a line continuation character if *any* character is placed after it on the line, not just comments. You can't even have whitespace after it in order for it to function as a line continuation character.